# Trouble connecting to FTP server with Passive ports

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I received FTP details. De credentials included a Passive port-range, which I am not familiar with. I tried to Google my issue, but I failed to find a solution.

When I try to connect to the FTP server via my FileZilla client, I get the following error:

> Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
> Status:   Initializing TLS... Status: Verifying certificate...
> Status:   TLS connection established. Status: Logged in
> Status:   Retrieving directory listing... Command:    PWD Response:   257 "/"
> is the current directory Command: TYPE I Response:    200 Type set to I
> Command:  PASV Response:  227 Entering Passive Mode
> (178,21,114,163,139,80). Command: MLSD Error: Connection timed out
> after 20 seconds of inactivity Error: Failed to retrieve directory
> listing

I am trying to figure out if this is a problem on my end. What should I do in order to connect to think FTP server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection to FileZilla FTP server works, but directory listing fails](https://superuser.com/questions/729876/connection-to-filezilla-ftp-server-works-but-directory-listing-fails)

Answer (score -1):

Changing Encryption to "Only use plain FTP (insecure)" in the site manager fixed it for me.

Comment: Disabling encryption is not not a fix. Anyway, for an explanation, see [File transfer with vsftpd does not work with TLS, but does work with unencrypted connection](https://superuser.com/q/1476711/213663).

Comment: You're completely right, it works for now though. I appreciate the link. I will definitely look into that.